# Entity Framework Repository Pattern in DAL, how to implement Update functions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, data-access-layer

or one of our projects (a C# Windows Service, mainly for processing data from external resources and read/write this data to a SQL Server database) we have implemented the Repository Pattern in the DAL, and we created a repository class for each POCO object (which represents a table row). The use of these Repository classes is managed by a Unit of Work pattern, so all Repositories share the same DbContext within a single unit of work, but maybe that's irrelevant to the quesion.

The repository class for, let's say a Customer entity, is implemented as following:

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;
    public CustomerRepository(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer(string id)
    {
        return _context.Customers.Find(new object[] {id});
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers(Func<Customer,bool> predicate )
    {
        return _context.Customers.Where(predicate);
    }
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomerByCity(string city)
    {
        return _context.Customers.Where(c=>s.City.Equals(city));
    }


    public void SetAge(string id, byte age)
    {
         _context.Customers.Find(new object[] { id }).Age = age;
    }

    public void Update(Customer customer)
    {
        _context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

}
```

Now i have a few questions about what is best practice for the update-methods:

- Is it recomended to have separate methods for updating specific fields in de database, like the SetAge() method?
- Or Is it recommended to get the Customer object to our BLL (with GetCustomer(id)), and just set the properties in the BLL like
  customer.Age = 35;, and then save this changes?

The update operations are mostly limited to a single field in a single row.

Maybe anyone would like to share some real-world thoughts with me?

Comment: If you think of the practicality of having a specific update operation for all your properties then the answer is fairly obvious. Also, that sort of approach probably isn't going to scale very well considering you will be making multiple trips to the DB to update the same object.

Comment: @James The update operations are mostly limited to a single field in a single row, so having multiple roundtrips is not an issue here. As far it's relevant, the changes are tracked by Entity Framework (changes are staying in memory), and the record will be commited to the database in one trip, when calling SaveChanges on our context object.

Comment: well for me, `SetAge` is domain logic and as such doesn't really belong in the repository layer. If you are asking is there any *harm* in doing what you are doing then the answer is no. However, consider things like the impact of editing an entity will be i.e. removing/renaming a property or adding a new property. All you are really doing is giving yourself unnecessary extra work, EF is clever enough to only update what has changed.

Comment: As an aside, I predict a problem with your Save. Quoting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx : "A DbContext instance represents a combination of the Unit Of Work and Repository patterns". The IDbSets are the repositories and the SaveChanges should be the responsibility of the Unit of Work. I recommend you move that method into the unit of work class

Comment: @Colin you are very right. The save method is actually part of my unit of work class. Must be sneaked in this examle while copy pasting from my project... Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Some argue that EF IS the unit of work and repository and that you should let it do the work for you.  I'm slowly coming around to this way of thinking.  EF is really good at managing all of this, and it's pointless to re-write tools that already exist.

Something to think about...

Comment: oh no i thought i was on the right track with this implementation, but this may change my way of thinking. Can you tell me why some tutorials suggesting this approach (like http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application )? I'm getting a little bit confused about what to implement myself, and in which layer of my application...

Comment: Ok, that article is using the UOW pattern to encapsulate the Context and repositories so that you can unit test without hitting the database.  Again, this is just my personal opinion, but I disagree with this philosophy.  Changing the DB schema is an all too frequent thing to do, and if you aren't hitting the actual test Sql Server (or whatever database you're using), how can you possibly know if your DB change broke something in a completely different method than the one you are testing??  IMO, you need to hit the DB when you unit test.  Others will disagree with me.

Comment: As for which layers do what, here's what I do... I create an MVC app as the top layer, then a Business Logic under that, then a EntityModel under that.  I do a little bit of T4 trickery and actually create a 4th project that all of the projects have access to which contains the POCOs.  The BusinessLogic is really respoinsible for doing all of the access to the DB.  Your MVC layer will call a business logic layer, which should NEVER return an IQueryable.  It should always be ICollection at this point.  If you need more help, email me at scottieslg at gmail dot com and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your detailed opinion with me, it's very close to the approach i had in mind (except in my case there is no Presentation Layer (it's a service), but i get the point. One thing sounds strange to me, you're saying "The BusinessLogic is really respoinsible for doing all of the access to the DB". Is there no DAL in your approach, or do you consider your EF DbContext / DbSets as your DAL??? Very curious about this point.

Comment: As I re-read my comment, it should have said the BusinessLogic is responsible for access to EF, not the DB.  EF accesses the DB.  However, there is no project that is specifically for data access.  I mean, if you think about it, your BLL isn't ACTUALLY doing data access.  It's just doing LINQ and letting LINQ to Sq/EF do the data access.  EF handles all the transactional aspects, the joins, the changes, additions, etc.  What exactly would your DAL do??  Expose a Save method that calls context.Save()?  Why bother?  Let EF do it's job.  It can do it better than you can.

Answer (score 2):

Im inclined to agree with Daryal. But would emphasise you dont quiet have the class repository model right. Ideally You Want the Repository to be generic. Operate on Full objects and provide DAL services.

```
 public class DAL.Repository<poco> {

    //methods for CRUD, get List, search whatever you see as right
    // eg ...add error handling....
    void add(poco p){
       context.attach(p);
    ... 
 }


//  The domain/core model layer would have much of the object based business logic
 public class CORE.PocoXYZ {
    //all the get sets and methods required to manipulate the object
 }


// And your Unit of Work Class
Public class DAL.UoW{
    context.savechanges();
}


So i would suggest you perform object level Data storage in the DAL. But do all teh object manipulation in the core.  The DAL would control the save in a UoW class that managed all Repositories.
```

A service or UI layer might inject the UoW/Repository layer into the Core layer.

Answer (score 1):

- Is it recomended to have separate methods for updating specific fields in de database, like the SetAge() method?

I do not think it will be wise to have seperate operations for each property. You will endup with methods encapsulating properties. Also, instead of implementing methods for each type, why not creating a base repository to implement commmon operations? Instead of `GetAllCustomers` you may implement `GetAll` in a base class and derive all your repositories from this base repository.

- Or Is it recommended to get the Customer object to our BLL (with GetCustomer(id)), and just set the properties in the BLL like customer.Age = 35;, and then save this changes?

I think the problem is not where you change the properties, the problem is the [anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). You have a seperate business layer, which modifies objects using repository methods. This violates the object orienteed approach which dictates objects shall have both properties and methods.

Comment: Entity Framework models are DTO's, not domain objects. A domain object containing business logic would be a Customer that checks whether the age being set is at least `0`.

Comment: @CodeCaster It does not prevent you from having domain objects from generated code; also I have not seen anything indicating EF in the question.

Comment: This is the DAL, not the BL. We don't know anything about OP's BL. For EF, see the question's tags.

Comment: @daryal I'm aware of the base-class suggestion, but kept this out of the example for simplicity. I will read your link to Fowlers post about the anemic domain Model.

Comment: I think the business layer is not relevant, it's just a service processing incoming data from TCP sockets, and this data needs to reach the database through the DAL.